# sharepoint 2013 doesn't render html correctly after deployment

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, sharepoint-2013

I use ASP.Net/MVC (.Net Framework 4.5) to program a Sharepoint 2013 Provider hosted app. If I press F5 to test my application I have no problem with the rendered result.

But if I deploy it onto my iis server and install the package on sharepoint 2013 the html will not be rendered correctly.

The funny thing is that it will still render correctly on any other major browser (Firefox, Opera, Chrome). Since my company uses only ie (people don't have any rights to install additional software) I need to have it render correctly on ie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I found the answer to my own question I want to share it here so if anyone hits the same problem he/she can make use of the answer.

It was a problem with Internet Explorer 11's "Compatibility View settings". I had to uncheck the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" checkbox to render the HTML correctly.